# Consider the function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function

$$ 
G(t) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \mbox {t is rational} \\ 
e^t & \mbox {t is irrational}
\end{cases} $$

Find the set of real numbers at which $G(t)$ is continuous. Justify.

Here are my thoughts:
I know how to prove that it is continuous at $t=0$ but I am stuck how to show that it is not continuous when $t \neq 0$.  I am pretty sure I have to show two cases, when say m is rational and when is irrational but I dont know how to show this.

Comment: I would try a sequential argument and use the denseness of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: Between a rational and _any other point_, there exists an irrational. Between an irrational and _any other point_, there exists a rational. (There's a proof involving the decimal expansions of the numbers, but I doubt you need to prove that.)

Answer (score 0):

A function is continuous at some point, if the limit of the function on sufficiently small intervals approaching that point exists and this limit is equal to the function at that point.

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta t\to 0} G(t+\Delta t)=G(t)$$

Show that such a limit does not exist for any point other than $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $e^r$ is irrational for a rational $r\not =0$.

$G(t)$ is not continuous on every nonzero rational number $t_r$ since $G(t_r)=1$ while the limit of $G(t)$ as $t\rightarrow t_r$ is an irrational number. The condition for continuity is not satisfied. So for every rational number except 0 $G(t)$ is discontinuous.

Try to show what happen if we consider the irrationals.

Comment: Why should $e^r$ be irrational if $r \not=0$? $e^{\log2}=2$

Comment: Got your point bharb, found it here,http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number. Will edit my answer now.